# Redirect after succesfull google recapta

Tags: php

this is my code i am currently working. but i need only click to redirect to next page

```
<title></title>
    <script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="index.php">
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxxx"></div>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>



<?php
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST")
    {
        //form submitted

        //check if other form details are correct

        //verify captcha
        $recaptcha_secret = "xxxxxxxxxg";
        $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$recaptcha_secret."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
        $response = json_decode($response, true);
        if($response["success"] === true)
        {
            echo "Logged In Successfully";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "You are a robot";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: ok, thats great, so from us you want what?

Comment: @Irfan Ali Why not posting your code as we're here to help you out by solving an issue, not to write the entire code for you... Would you please take a few minutes to post your code and add it to your question by clicking the "Edit" link? Replace the secret/private key with something else as this should be kept secret and should be only known by you.

Comment: @jabg i did it kindly check

Answer (score 1):

To post only for actual clicks is not the answer against robots, you need to create a form with a hidden token and check if the recaptcha and token are valid and then validate user log in.

```
<title></title>
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php

  if ( !isset($_POST['Submit']) ){
     // Genarate token 
     $token = md5(uniqid(rand(),TRUE));
     $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
     $_SESSION['token_time'] = time();
  }

?>
<form method="post" action="index.php">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="xxxxx"></div>
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $token;?>"/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

```
<?php

if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST")
{
    //form submitted

    //check if other form details are correct

    //verify captcha
    $recaptcha_secret = "xxxxxxxxxg";
    $response = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$recaptcha_secret."&response=".$_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
    $response = json_decode($response, true);
    if($response["success"] === true)
    {
        // Logged In Successfully
        if ( $_POST['token'] != $_SESSION['token'] ){
            // Didn't came from the site
            header('Location: login.php');
        } else {
            header('Location: index.php');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Not Logged In Successfully
        header('Location: login.php');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of echo'ing "Logged In Successfully", use:

```
echo '<script type="text/javascript">',
  'location.replace( "'.$url.'" );'
  ,'</script>';
```

with $url set to whatever page you want to redirect to.

Comment: i need full code.. above script is for form submit.. i want user redirect if they are real.. just on click